# how to eliminate elements from all vectors in a list that are present in a vecor in r

Tags: r

I have a list contain different vectors with different length

```
list1 <- list(a = 1:10, b = 3:20, c = c(1,3,7, 9,18,20,24,28))
```

I would like to eliminate any elements from all vectors in `list1` that are present in a vector

```
 d <- c(1,3,7,8,20)
```

I expect the result as:

```
 list(a = c(2,4:6,9:10), b = c(4:6,9:19), c = c(9,18,24,28))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example

```
lapply(list1, setdiff, d)
```

gives

```
$a
[1]  2  4  5  6  9 10

$b
 [1]  4  5  6  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

$c
[1]  9 18 24 28
```

Read `?setdiff` for related functions.

Comment: this function is in two packages, `dplyr` and `base`, which one?

Comment: @user3354212 Read the help page for base. It automatically uses the base one (by redirection/method dispatch) even if dplyr is loaded.